# SoundPool sound stops only once?

Tags: android, soundpool

I have a Sound class:

```
  package dubpad.brendan;

  import android.media.SoundPool;

    public class Sound {
   SoundPool soundPool;
    int soundID;

    public Sound(SoundPool soundPool, int soundID) {
        this.soundPool = soundPool;
        this.soundID = soundID;
    }

    public void play(float volume) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 0, -1, 1);
    }

    public void stop(int soundID){
        soundPool.stop(soundID);
    }


    public void dispose() {
        soundPool.unload(soundID);
    }


    }
```

and I have an activity that extends a button :

```
package dubpad.brendan;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestButton extends Button {
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
int soundID = soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.dub1, 0);
Sound sound = new Sound(soundPool, soundID);


public TestButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
  if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
sound.play(1);


 } 




if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
sound.stop(soundID);
}


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

 }
```

On the first action down the sound plays, and on first action up the sound pauses. But every single action up after the 1st one doesn't pause the sound. In simple words, the pause only works once.

Comment: so why do you use `soundId` as parameter for `stop()` method and don't use it as parameter for `play()` method?

Comment: Sorry, that shouldn't be there in the stop() method. It's just sound.stop(); I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Did you look at your LogCat? SoundPool is usually pretty verbose whenever something's not working right.

Comment: okay, `SoundPool.play()` method returns you some int, try to use stop with this int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

===EDIT=== (I think my original answer was wrong, changing it)

You need to change Sound class to return the streamId from play:

```
public int play(float volume) {
  return soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 0, -1, 1);
}
```

And then you can store this value inside of TestButton:

```
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
  mStreamId = sound.play(1);
}
```

Then use mStreamId to stop the sound:

```
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
   sound.stop(mStreamId);
}
```

The key here is that you want to call `stop` on the `streamId`, not the `soundId`. A soundId refers to the particular sound resource, but the streamId refers to a single instance of the sound playing. So if you play the same sound 3 times you have one soundId and three streamIds.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! But I don't understand how to record streamID, and haven't found anything else where, please assist me.

Comment: I don't understand the question, what do you mean 'record streamID'? Your code looks fine other than that you need to call soundPool.load again after you call soundpool.stop.

Comment: Hey Tim! Sorry for not being clear, my question's how do I get the value returned by the play() function? Additionally, load function doesn't work within the if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ But as I was reading about it, apparently I need to use sound.stop(streamId); but everyone time I use streamId it says it's not defined. So how do I go about this, I'm clueless.

Comment: StreamId is returned by soundPool.play, but you're throwing it away in your sound class. See my edited answer. @ChrisBrendan