# switching from Media Player to Media Player force close

Tags: android, media-player, forceclose

hi ive been working on my app and have found a hurdle in an activity i just cant seem to overcome. the activity is essentially a large novelty piano with 8 keys that play sounds there are 6 buttons along the side that change the picture of the notes and the notes themselves, this i accomplished :-) now i would like to add a background song to each different set of notes (instruments) only when i do the app crashes i have set the mediaplayer at the top (globally?) using MediaPlayer mp; MediaPlayer mp2; etc and im using this in my code to check if any music is playing, stop it, release it, and then play the piece i want,

```
if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
}
if(mp2!=null&&mp2.isPlaying()){
    mp2.stop();
    mp2.release();
}
if(mp3!=null&&mp3.isPlaying()){
    mp3.stop();
    mp3.release();
}
mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(MusicActivity.this, R.raw.snaps);
mp3.setLooping(true);
mp3.start();
```

this again works but going from one to another and then back crashes the app. is there something else i should be doing? or is just an out of memory error?

EDIT--
 Thanks to ranjk89 for his help

changed to soundpools but they wont stop ranjk89 suggests referring to the stream id and not the sound id looking for a little more clarification if possible i have

```
farmback =0;
drumback =0;
```

at the top then its loaded in oncreate using

```
drumback = sp.load(this, R.raw.snaps,1);
farmback = sp.load(this, R.raw.oldmacdonaldbeta,1);
```

and then way down, in the same method i change the button icons, not the same method i change all my other sounds for my notes i call

```
  sp.stop(drumback);              
  sp.play(farmback, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);
```

in one and

```
sp.stop(farmback);              
  sp.play(drumback, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);
```

in another but there are 6 different instruments in total that all need a different backing track which should stop when the instrument is changed and play the one associated to it so something like

```
if (sp !=null && sp.isplaying()){
sp.stop();
sp.play(dumback);

}
```

but obviously this is not possible any help appreciated

Comment: how big is each 'song' ..i mean how many seconds are they ..maybe a soundPool would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Initial reaction is, you shouldn't be using multiple [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) at all in the first place.

I would suggest you to use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) as you can load all the media(audio) initially, once they are all loaded you can play them at will. Plus you won't have multiple players which would downsize the complexity of your code.

But if you do want to use Media player,

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer). But be aware that once you [release](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) you will not be able to reuse that instance of MediaPlayer. Even if you are using multiple MediaPlayers, do not call release on them unless you are sure you don't want to use them any more. Use stop()/prepare() combination.

For application doing too much work on the Main Thread,

If you either use a SoundPool or only one MediaPlayer and still bump in to the same issue, Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Android dev site has a very good [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html) on this

Comment: I will do that now will -1 loop?

Comment: Tried this thinking it would be similar to the media player but apparently not how do I stop a soundpool? sp.stop(int) doesn't seem to be doing it the backing tracks just play over each other

Comment: i used -1 to set it looping is this the issue should it just be sp.setlooping

Comment: I suggested sound pool because you can load multiple audios initially then play them whenever you want. You can stop and start them individually when where you want- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12936732/713778

Comment: Note that you have the store the streamId returned by play() and pass it to stop()

Comment: okay i think you were right to suggest soundpools its all ive been using thus far and i do understand them to a degree i was under the impression that media player was best practice for looping music in background and soundpools for effects but the tracks are short so i think your right but im struggling with it as they wont stop, im adding some code to my question could you have a look and ill accept yours as the right answer many thanks

Comment: how do i find the streamid? or do i declare it?

Comment: Do something like this, int mStreamId = sound.play(soundId);

Comment: im still struggling with this ive changed things to reflect your answer but i still have the sounds overlapping im trying to do this, if (mStreamId1 !=0 && mStreamId2 !=0 && mStreamId3 !=0 && mStreamId4 !=0) {
                            sp.stop(mStreamId1);
                            sp.stop(mStreamId2);
                            sp.stop(mStreamId3);
                            sp.stop(mStreamId4);
                        }

                       mStreamId1 = sp.play(farmback, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);
                        sp.setLoop(farmback,-1);

Comment: You can specify the number of streams you want playing at any time in the constructor- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html Hope thats helps.

Comment: Yeah okay just for future reference I fixed this by adding a new sound pool for all my backing tracks and changed the stream to only allow one stream to play at a time as mentioned above. Not what I wanted but in some ways a better solution thank you @ranjk89